# Не подключается СSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня возникла такая проблема - есть файлы styleForLaba.css, program.js, laba5.2.html,(Прикреплю их сюда),при подключении css (либо через css файл,либо через style в html файле) не работают описанные свойства для классов.Пробовал добавлять стили через DevTools и все работает.Подскажите,пожалуйста,в чем может быть проблема?

```js
questions = [
    {
        idQuest: 1,
        textQuest: "HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) является:"
    },
    {
        idQuest: 2,
        textQuest: "Инструкция браузеру, указывающая способ отображения текста: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 3,
        textQuest: "Web-страница (документ HTML) представляет собой: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 4,
        textQuest: "Гипертекст - это: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 5,
        textQuest: "Вычеслите: 44<sub>5</sub> + 22<sub>3</sub>"
    },
    {
        idQuest: 6,
        textQuest: "Известно,что в кодовой таблице ASCII десятичный код символа 1 равен 49.Каков десятичный код символа 9? "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 7,
        textQuest: "Дано: а = 20<sub>10</sub>,b = 22<sub>8</sub>.Какое из чисел <i>c</i>,записанных в двоичной системе,отвечает условию <i>b&ltc&lta</i>?  "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 8,
        textQuest: "К устройствам вывода информации относится? "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 9,
        textQuest: "Устройство,которое не используется для долговременного хранения информации - это? "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 10,
        textQuest: "Поле, значение которого однозначно определяет запись в таблице базы данных, называется "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 11,
        textQuest: "Графика с представлением изображения в виде совокупности точек называется"
    },
    {
        idQuest: 12,
        textQuest: "Под искусственным интелектом обычно понимают "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 13,
        textQuest: "В виде комбинации оттенков,  каких  трех основных цветов представлена каждая точка, из массива цветовых точек экрана монитора? "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 14,
        textQuest: "Стандартизация - это: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 15,
        textQuest: "Тексты, рисунки, фотографии, световые и звуковые сигналы, радиоволны, электрические нервные импульсы, магнитные записи это: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 16,
        textQuest: "Как называют сеть, в которой один ПК главный?"
    },
    {
        idQuest: 17,
        textQuest: "Какое, из перечисленных устройств, имеет узкоспециализированный процессор и оперативную память? "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 18,
        textQuest: "Электронная почта (E-mail) позволяет передавать: "
    },
    {
        idQuest: 19,
        textQuest: "Как называется процесс передачи сообщений в электронном виде?"
    },
    {
        idQuest: 20,
        textQuest: "Почтовый ящик абонента электронной почты - это "
    }
];
answers = [
    {
        idAnsw: 1,
        idQuest: 1,
        textAnsw: "одним из средств при создании web-страниц",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 2,
        idQuest: 1,
        textAnsw: "системой программирования",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 3,
        idQuest: 1,
        textAnsw: "графическим редактором",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 4,
        idQuest: 1,
        textAnsw: "системой управления базами данных",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 5,
        idQuest: 2,
        textAnsw: "программный код",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 6,
        idQuest: 2,
        textAnsw: "тэг ",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 7,
        idQuest: 2,
        textAnsw: "файл",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 8,
        idQuest: 2,
        textAnsw: "кегль",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 9,
        idQuest: 3,
        textAnsw: "текстовый файл с расширением txt или doc",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 10,
        idQuest: 3,
        textAnsw: "текстовый файл с расширением htm или html",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 11,
        idQuest: 3,
        textAnsw: "двоичный файл с расширением com или exe",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 12,
        idQuest: 3,
        textAnsw: "графический файл с расширением gif или jpg",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 13,
        idQuest: 4,
        textAnsw: "текст очень большого размера",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 14,
        idQuest: 4,
        textAnsw: "текст, в котором используется шрифт большого размера",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 15,
        idQuest: 4,
        textAnsw: "структурированный текст, где возможны переходы по выделенным меткам",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 16,
        idQuest: 4,
        textAnsw: "текст, в который вставлены объекты с большим объемом информации",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 17,
        idQuest: 5,
        textAnsw: "1 111",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 18,
        idQuest: 5,
        textAnsw: "10 000",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 19,
        idQuest: 5,
        textAnsw: "10 111",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 20,
        idQuest: 5,
        textAnsw: "10 011",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 21,
        idQuest: 6,
        textAnsw: "51",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 22,
        idQuest: 6,
        textAnsw: "53",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 23,
        idQuest: 6,
        textAnsw: "55",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 24,
        idQuest: 6,
        textAnsw: "57",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 25,
        idQuest: 7,
        textAnsw: "100<sub>10</sub>",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 26,
        idQuest: 7,
        textAnsw: "100 000<sub>2</sub>",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 27,
        idQuest: 7,
        textAnsw: "222<sub>3</sub>",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 28,
        idQuest: 7,
        textAnsw: "66<sub>8</sub>",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 29,
        idQuest: 8,
        textAnsw: "Монитор",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 30,
        idQuest: 8,
        textAnsw: "Клавиатура",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 31,
        idQuest: 8,
        textAnsw: "Микрофон",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 32,
        idQuest: 8,
        textAnsw: "Сканер",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 33,
        idQuest: 9,
        textAnsw: "Жесткий диск",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 34,
        idQuest: 9,
        textAnsw: "Флэш-Карта",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 35,
        idQuest: 9,
        textAnsw: "Оперативное запоминающее устройство(ОЗУ)",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 36,
        idQuest: 9,
        textAnsw: "CD-диск",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 37,
        idQuest: 10,
        textAnsw: "Внешнее",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 38,
        idQuest: 10,
        textAnsw: "Внутренее",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 39,
        idQuest: 10,
        textAnsw: "Индексированное",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 40,
        idQuest: 10,
        textAnsw: "Ключевое",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 41,
        idQuest: 11,
        textAnsw: "Фрактальная",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 42,
        idQuest: 11,
        textAnsw: "Векторная",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 43,
        idQuest: 11,
        textAnsw: "Растровая",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 44,
        idQuest: 11,
        textAnsw: "Прямоугольная",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 45,
        idQuest: 12,
        textAnsw: "пособности компьютерных систем к таким действиям, которые назывались бы интеллектуальными, если бы исходили от человека",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 46,
        idQuest: 12,
        textAnsw: "класс пакетов включает: информационные системы, поддерживающие диалог на естественном языке",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 47,
        idQuest: 12,
        textAnsw: "способности, связанные с человеческим мышлением",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 48,
        idQuest: 12,
        textAnsw: "интеллектуальные пакеты прикладных программ, позволяющие решать прикладные задачи без программирования",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 49,
        idQuest: 13,
        textAnsw: "черный, белый и красный",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 50,
        idQuest: 13,
        textAnsw: "черный, синий и белый",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 51,
        idQuest: 13,
        textAnsw: "красный, синий и зеленый",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 52,
        idQuest: 13,
        textAnsw: "белый, синий и красный",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 53,
        idQuest: 14,
        textAnsw: "инструмент государственной технической политики, деятельность по установлению правил и характеристик в целях их добровольного многократного использования, направленная на достижение упорядоченности в сферах производства и обращения продукции",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 54,
        idQuest: 14,
        textAnsw: "виды нормативно-технических документов в Российской Федерации",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 55,
        idQuest: 14,
        textAnsw: "стандарт, утвержденный национальным органом РФ по стандартизации",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 56,
        idQuest: 14,
        textAnsw: "стандарт, принятый международной организацией",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 57,
        idQuest: 15,
        textAnsw: "формы информации",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 58,
        idQuest: 15,
        textAnsw: "виды информации",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 59,
        idQuest: 15,
        textAnsw: "способы обработки информации",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 60,
        idQuest: 15,
        textAnsw: "информационные процессы",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 61,
        idQuest: 16,
        textAnsw: "сеть – клиент",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 62,
        idQuest: 16,
        textAnsw: "сеть - сервер",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 63,
        idQuest: 16,
        textAnsw: "сеть клиент - сервер",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 64,
        idQuest: 16,
        textAnsw: "серверная сеть",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 65,
        idQuest: 17,
        textAnsw: "принтер",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 66,
        idQuest: 17,
        textAnsw: "сканер",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 67,
        idQuest: 17,
        textAnsw: "копир",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 68,
        idQuest: 17,
        textAnsw: "ксерокс",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 69,
        idQuest: 18,
        textAnsw: "только сообщения и файлы",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 70,
        idQuest: 18,
        textAnsw: "только файлы и гипертекст",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 71,
        idQuest: 18,
        textAnsw: "только гипертекст и сообщения",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 72,
        idQuest: 18,
        textAnsw: "сообщения и приложенные файлы",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 73,
        idQuest: 19,
        textAnsw: "электронная почта",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 74,
        idQuest: 19,
        textAnsw: "спам",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 75,
        idQuest: 19,
        textAnsw: "рассылка сообщений",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 76,
        idQuest: 19,
        textAnsw: "пересылка сообщений",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 77,
        idQuest: 20,
        textAnsw: "часть оперативной памяти на сервере",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 78,
        idQuest: 20,
        textAnsw: "часть внешней памяти на сервере",
        isTrue: false
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 79,
        idQuest: 20,
        textAnsw: "часть оперативной памяти на рабочей станции",
        isTrue: true
    },
    {
        idAnsw: 80,
        idQuest: 20,
        textAnsw: "часть внешней памяти на рабочей станции",
        isTrue: false
    },

]
var NewArray = [];
function ResetTest() {
    document.body.innerHTML = " ";
    document.write('<div id="MustBeHidden">Введите количество вопросов n(будет n случайных вопросов) <input type =number min=2 max=20 name="number" id="number"><input type=button value=Сгенерировать onClick="randomTest()" ></div>');
    document.write('</form>');

}
function randomTest() {
    document.getElementById('MustBeHidden').style.display = "none";
    var n = document.getElementById('number').value;
    document.write("<h1>Тест </h1>");
    document.write("<form>");

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var prove = 1;
        while (prove > 0) {
            prove = 0;
            var m = +Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
            for (var k = 0; k <= NewArray.length; k++)
                if (m == NewArray[k]) prove++;
        }
        NewArray.push(m);
        document.write('<div class="quest" id = q' + questions[m].idQuest + ' > ' + (i + 1) + '. ' + questions[m].textQuest + "</div><div><ul>");
        for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
            if (answers[j].idQuest != questions[m].idQuest) continue;
            document.write('<li><input type =radio name=ansQ' + questions[i].idQuest + ' value=a' + questions[m].idQuest + '_' + answers[j].idAnsw + ' onClick="ChangeQuestionsColor()">' + answers[j].textAnsw + '</li>');
        }
        document.write('</ul></div>');


    }

    document.write('<input type = button value="Проверить тест" ' +
        'onClick = "checkTest()">');
    document.write('<input type = button value="Новый тест"' + 'onClick = "ResetTest()">');
    document.write('</form>');

    var EllementsOnPage = document.getElementsByClassName('quest');
    for (var i = 0; i < EllementsOnPage.length; i++) {
        EllementsOnPage[i].style.border = '5px outset green';
        EllementsOnPage[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        EllementsOnPage[i].style.color = 'white';
    }
    return NewArray;

}
function checkTest() {
    // формируем массив из всех элементов input на странице
    var arrAnswers = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    //переменная для подсчета правильных ответов
    var countCorrectAnswers = 0;
    // строка для накопления вопросов, на которые пользователь
    // ответил неверно
    var strUnCorrectAnswers = '';
    //количество вопросов, на которые пользователь дал ответ
    var questionChecked = 0;
    var ForCheckingAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName('quest');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (arrAnswers[i].checked) {
            questionChecked++;
            //проверяем правильность ответа, если ответ верный,
            //то увеличиваем количество верных ответов
            //в противном случае - заносим вопрос в строку неправильных
            if (isRightAnswer(arrAnswers[i].value)) countCorrectAnswers++;
            else strUnCorrectAnswers += getQuestion(arrAnswers[i].value)
                + "\n";
        }

    }
    // проверяем, на все ли вопросы ответил пользователь,
    // если на все вопросы есть ответы - выводим результат
    if (questionChecked != questions.length) {

        for (i = 0; i < ForCheckingAnswers.length; i++) {
            ForCheckingAnswers[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }


    }

    else if (countCorrectAnswers == questions.length)
        alert('Вы ответили правильно на все вопросы верно!')
    else alert("Количество правильных ответов: " +
        countCorrectAnswers +
        "\nВы ответили неверно на следующие вопросы:\n" +
        strUnCorrectAnswers);
}
function ChangeQuestionsColor() {
    var n = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var arrAnswers = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var CheckedQuestion = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (arrAnswers[j + i * 4].checked) CheckedQuestion = true;
        if (CheckedQuestion == true) document.getElementById('q' + questions[NewArray[i]].idQuest).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
/* функция выдает верный или неверный вариант ответа выбрал
пользователь на некоторый вопрос, переданный параметр - значение типа
a_2_5, где 2 - номер вопроса, 5 - номер ответа*/
function isRightAnswer(str) {
    //выделяем номер вопроса
    var idUserQuest = str.substring(1, str.indexOf('_'));
    //выделяем номер ответа
    var idUserAnsw = str.substring(str.indexOf('_') + 1)
    // ищем в массиве ответов вариант, выбранный пользователем,
    // и возвращаем результат, правильный он или нет
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i].idQuest != idUserQuest) continue;
        if (answers[i].idAnsw != idUserAnsw) continue;
        return answers[i].isTrue;
    }
    return false;
}
// формируем текст вопроса,
//переданный параметр - значение типа a_2_5, где 2 - номер вопроса
function getQuestion(str) {
    //выделяем номер вопроса
    var idUserQuest = str.substring(1, str.indexOf('_'));
    //ищем в массиве текст нужного вопроса
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (questions[i].idQuest != idUserQuest) continue;
        return questions[i].textQuest;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
.quest {
  background-color: green;
}
.quest {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <style>
      body {
        font-size: 100px;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: circle;
      }
      .quest {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .quest {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
    </style> -->
  </head>
  <body onload="ResetTest()" style="font-size:100px">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="program.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Есть небольшая ошибка в html,забыл убрать комментарий для стиля,но и без него не работает

Comment: Пробовал через ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="name.css">```? В head

Comment: Пробовал,все равно не работает.У меня есть подозрение,что css файл,вызываемый html,имеет сломанное имя,но я не знаю как это проверить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что выполнение [document.write](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write) у вас прописано при загрузке, что переписывает всю страницу, и `head`, в котором были все подключения. Вы сразу при загрузке страницы пытаетесь писать html код в js. Можно сделать проще и правильнее: через [document.createElement](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document) он не будет влиять на подключения, а уже в созданный таким образом элемент дописывать через inner. Вот пример:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "first";
  //div.innerHTML = "";
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = "second";
li.innerHTML = "Text "+i;
ul.appendChild(li);
}
div.appendChild(ul);
var bod = document.getElementById('bod');//Добавить id=bod в body
bod.appendChild(div);
```

Ну, и соответственно его надо писать после body:

```
<body id="bod" style="font-size:12px">
</body>
```